# Why doesn't my CSV file get written correctly and downloaded through the PHP script

Tags: php, csv, download

I'm trying to get the contents of a existing CSV file to another CSV and download, but currently it doesn't write the data inside the existing CSV file correctly

**My Code**:

```
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"report.csv\"");
$f_pointer=fopen("result.csv","r"); // file pointer

while(!feof($f_pointer)) {
  $data=fgetcsv($f_pointer);
  echo $data;
}
```

**What it returns**:

```
> > <br /> <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'> <tr><th
> align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span
> style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size:
> x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Array to string conversion in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\162\dld1.php on line <i>9</i></th></tr> <tr><th
> align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
> <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left'
> bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left'
> bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left'
> bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left'
> bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr> <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'
> align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'
> align='center'>0.0000</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'
> align='right'>135152</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td
> title='C:\xampp\htdocs\162\dld1.php'
> bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\dld1.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr> </table></font>
```

**What I want returned instead**:

```
17  testproject TDD 1   2   27  10/13/2014 10:19    10/2/2014 7:25  Win7    Windows Desktop Firefox 33
17  testproject DTD 1   2   27  10/13/2014 10:19    10/2/2014 7:25  Win7    Windows Desktop Firefox 33
```

**My CSV file**:

```
tID tname       accountname accountid   status  imprcount   earliest_imp        recent_imp       platform   device          browser browser_version
17  testproject TDD         1           2       27          10/13/2014 10:19    10/2/2014 7:25   Win7       Windows Desktop Firefox 33
17  testproject DTD         1           2       27          10/13/2014 10:19    10/2/2014 7:25   Win7       Windows Desktop Firefox 33
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
echo $data;
```

to

```
var_dump($data);
```

the problem is cause by the fgetcsv() because it returns an array and not string

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: thanks mate but it still it gives all that font colour, align and all that rubbish instead of a clear csv doc

Comment: you still encounter the same exact error?, please post what your csv file exactly contains(but just include the first 3 lines)

Comment: you CSV is not well formatted the contents per columns must be separated with commas

Comment: still doesn't work? please update your post with the recent csv content